# Javascript Detect selected items

Tags: javascript, forms

I have the following code. I need to know the selected fields. [] is needed for PHP. Without [] it works but in the following codes an error occurs.

```
<form name="tform">
<select multiple name="test[]">
<option selected>1</option><option>2</option></select></form>
<script type=text/javascript>
var x=document.tform.test;
for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++) {
      if (x.options[i].selected) {
            xselected++;
      }
}
alert(xselected);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `var x=document.tform.test;` with the following:

```
var x = document.tform.getElementsByName("test[]")[0];
```

This way you should be able to select the `<select>`-element.

Comment: Or better yet, just assign the `select` an ID and use `document.getElementById`.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to suggest that to, but i tought that he maybe doesn't want to change his Markup.

Comment: x = document.tform.getElementsByName("test[]")[0];